# How to resize the webview According to the size of device Screen in android studio

Tags: java, android, webview

I've created an android studio project with web view. Web view contains responsive website. I've tested my app with smart phone(nokia3). but I don't know how it works with tab. because I don't have a tablet. but I found some solutions, Can you tell me which one is correct ?

A:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);  
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

B:

```
WebSettings webSettings = appView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Comment: Mr.oneday, make sure that set the width and height to match_parent and your parent layout is to be set to match_parent, all these are not required. Thank u

Comment: Thank you @Varma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are the same.
Both are correct in terms of functionality.

You can choose anyone of them.

**A.**
Settings of webview is being modified by directly referencing from the view

**B.** Its taking the `WebSettings` object first and then modifying its state.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: WebView webView;

        **webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);**


after adding this into onCreate method my app goes "....has stopped".
Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Webview width and hieght match_parent. but make sure if you set padding then remove the padding.